# GET request to Contiki @ \.well-known\core returns NULL

Tags: java, client, server, contiki, iot

I have a trouble about an IoT project, I'll explain it better :

I have a CLIENT based on Californium Java that has to make a `GET` request to a Contiki based Server (based on Zolertia z1 node).
When I make the request, if the server node has too many resources or too many resource's attributes, the server reply is `NULL`.
Otherwise, it replies with a Core Link Format that contains the list of available resources stored on it.

Thank you all!
If you want some code, I'll post it.

Client CODE

```
Request rq = new Request(Code.GET);

            CoapResponse coapRe = coapClientCore.advanced(rq);
            if(coapRe != null)
                System.out.println(coapRe.getResponseText());
            else 
                System.out.println("is null");
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).